# THT: What is a squared annular “ring”?

Tags: kicad, footprint, through-hole

At least in KiCad, the footprints of through-hole pin headers have one squared annular “ring”, the other ones are round:

[image]

*What does the square indicate?*

(Also I’m wondering if there is perhaps a convention of connecting GND to it.)

Comment: have you  also noticed that the square usually has a `1` label?

Comment: I'd say clear duplicate.

Comment: At least for KiCad the answer is very simple. It is specified that way in the library convention: http://kicad-pcb.org/libraries/klc/F7.3/ (Answer in comments as i can not create an answer to a duplicate question.)

We are however slowly transitioning to using rounded rectangle pads instead of square ones. (Benefits: Better solder joint, more space for traces.)

Comment: @RenePöschl Can you delete the link (or comment linking to the old site)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It’s just a quick and easy way to distinguish which connector pad is pin 1.

Particularly when there is no silkscreen present or just when routing the PCB.

Comment: And there is **not** a convention of connecting ground to it!  Don't even think that thought!

Comment: Of course there's a convention of connecting ground to it. It's just that there are also 17 other conventions.